# Rails inverse_of confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, relationship

I have these two models: Team and User.

Each user can have team and each team has many users. But I want to call team.users with team.members. I managed to do this with class_name, but I also need to have access to Team by User. In other words user.team should return me the team, in which the User is. Here is what I came up with...

My models are as follows:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, foreign_key: 'id', class_name: 'User', :inverse_of => :team
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, :inverse_of => :user
end
```

(I tried with :inverse_of => :members too, inside the User model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `:inverse_of` right, at least when you use `:inverse_of => :members`. The problem here is the foreign key. `foreign_key` specifies the name of the key-column in the other table, so in your case in the user-table. If you specify just `id`, the id of the user would be used. Just leave it to the default by not specifying an foreign key, then its `team_id`.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :team
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, :inverse_of => :members
end
```

And try to not mix hash-syntax from ruby 1.8 (`:key => 'value'`) with the new syntax from ruby 1.9 (`key: 'value'`).